# Unusual behaviour with String.Split

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split

I came across this problem this morning. Here is the code to replicate:

```
Dim s As String = "C:\program files (x86)\test1\abc.exe"
Console.WriteLine(s.Split("abc.exe")(0))
```

The result is: `c:\progra` and I would expect it to be `c:\program files (x86)\test1\`

Any ideas what it splits at that point?

Comment: The method calls on MSDN don't suggest that there's one that simply takes a string. Are you sure you've not passed a char[] instead? Then it would split on the first 'a' it came to in 'program'

Comment: Also, if you are just wanting the folder the program resides in `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s))` might be a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload. You should be using the one taking a string as a delimiter, that is:

```
Dim s As String = "C:\program files (x86)\test1\abc.exe"
Console.WriteLine(s.Split(New String() {"abc.exe"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0))
```

CLARIFICATION:

The behaviour you observed is one of the typical "drawbacks" of using `Option Strict Off` (that's why it is recommendable to always use `Option Strict On` if you are not 100% sure of what you are doing): you are using the overload taking a character as separator and VB.NET does not complain because converting automatically `string`s into `character`s is one of the things which `Option Strict On` does. As far as `"abc.exe"` does not match any character, VB.NET understands some default value (apparently, a blank space).

Conclusion: when you use `Split` with a string (consisting in one character or in 100) as separator, you should use the right overload (, as shown in my code).

Conclusion 2: write always `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't normally do VB so I may be wrong here but my guess would be it's treating your String as a char.

Does VB implicitly cast? If so could it be casting your string into a `char` instead? If it were to do so then it would take the value `a` which would then split at the `a` in `program` and explain the behavior your seeing.

Instead use provide the `StringSplitOptions` in this alternative [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method call.

Comment: I wouldn't ever have expected you to downvote my answer. Seriously you don't understand what the expression "wrong overload" means? The Split function behaves exactly the same in C#; there are many different overloads for different separators. Can you please, now remove your -1?

Comment: @varocarbas: In C# that simply wouldn't compile because you've not matched a valid signature - "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'". So from a C# perspective that is really weird behaviour. If you edit your answer (my vote's locked in until you do) I'll remove the downvote.